# abstract references to generic interfaces

Tags: c#, generics

Does anyone else feel that it might be useful if the runtime allowed references to members of a generic interface that were not specific to the generic type? I know the usual "workaround" is to create a non-generic interface as the base for the generic interface, but is there a valid reason against that base interface basically being automatic?

For example, given the following interface:

```
public interface IProcessor<T> 
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Process(T item);
}
```

I think it would be convenient to automatically allow something like this:

```
public void LogProcessor(IProcessor<> item)
{
        Trace.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

I'm curious to hear arguments against this (other than "stop being so lazy and just write the base interface").

Comment: How would it know what T you mean there?

Comment: It seems that to handle such a feature C# would have to become dynamically typed.

Comment: Paul Sasik. Such code after compilation can generate base interface for generics. And This is idea, but can cause some issues...

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about a feature that Java has, which is the ability to represent wildcarded generics.  For example, in Java you can declare an argument of type `IProcessor<?>`, which will work like your example describes.

Comment: Marc- That's the point, the LogProcessor function doesn't care about T.

Comment: @Daniel - I hadn't heard of that and it does sound exactly like what I need. I wonder why they didn't include that in C#.

Comment: @Paul - I don't see how this would have to be dynamically typed. The members of the interface that don't refer to T are known at compile/design time. The new c# "dynamic" type is still static even without this knowledge.

Comment: @WuffaloWill: While the C# and Java generics implementations are superficially similar at the source level, the compiler and runtime implementations are very different.  Java *needs* wildcards to be able to implement covariance and contravariance, while C# takes a very different approach.  The `<?>` notation in Java is primarily used for interoperability with raw types, which is an awkward feature introduced only for backwards compatibility with pre-generics code.  Chances are, the C# team just didn't see your use case (which is, admittedly, a rare case) as worth the necessary 100 points.

Answer (score 7):

You can just use a generic method:

```
public void LogProcessor<T>(IProcessor<T> item)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: I could, but what about a context where I don't know what T is? For example, what if I want to dynamically load (and log names) of all classes in an assembly that implement the IProcessor<> interface (I can check for the interface by using t.GetInterface(typeof(IProcessor<>).Name) != null)?

Comment: @WuffaloWIll: You can check for the generic one, then use reflection to call the generic method (with the appropriate type via MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx).  It's not pretty, but it will work in many cases.  However, for normal APIs where you're not using relfection, this works perfectly.

Comment: @Reed- Thanks for the reply. I do understand how to use generic methods in "normal APIs"; I suppose I should have worded my original response as "what about a context where I don't _care_ what T is?"

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why not is common language specification. And add such stuff is a big part of work and testing for microsoft framework developers. So its more easy is add base interface.
But anyway you can post you idea to microsoft forums